# WPF Combobox Category Grouping From Async Call

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, combobox, grouping

I can able to Group Data by its Categories to Combobox while Rendering {Initialization} by Setting below code like below

```
    _cboItem = new List<string>();
_cboitem=service.GetData();
    CollectionView cvs =     CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_cboItem);
cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new  PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
```

But If I bind combbox with Async call, Grouping is not happening.

code below

```
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_cboDocType, _lock);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDocTypeAsync());

    CollectionView cv=(CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_cboDocType);
      cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
      OnPropertyChanged("DocType");
```